# How to create a folder named by item's ID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I want is to have a folder created in `Content/Images` directory when new item is created. That folder should be named by item's ID.

Example:
`Content/Images/23412/`

But since the ID is 0 till database assigns new id, I wonder what options do I have?

Comment: Create it after the item has been saved?

Comment: You can use `scope_identity()` to get the last id generated after insert if we are talking about Sql Server

Comment: Try to get the last id, manually increment it and use that to save your item.

Comment: In `EntityFramework`, after saving your record, the `Item.ID` will be automatically bound to `auto-generated` value for your `item` `ID`.

Comment: You don't need implement anything. Entity Framework has done it for you. After executing `SaveChanges()` statement for insertion, just use `var newId = item.ID;` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the id after insert the data your your database :

```
myObject.Field1 = "value";
db.SaveChanges()

// You can retrieve the id from the object
int id = myObject.ColumnID;
```

Then create your folder :

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/" + id)
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
   // Try to create the directory.
   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```